# Is firebase configuration limits for conversion tracking (30 conversions events) are for App level for project level?

Tags: firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Is firebase configuration limits for conversion tracking (30 conversions events) are for App level for project level?
I have checked the [help center](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9237506?hl=en), however, it did not specify if the configuration limit is for app or project level, since I have multiple apps within a project, would like to know if every app have it's own conversion tracking limit of 30 conversions can be enabled and send to Google ads for conversion tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation on [conversion events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317518?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article):

> You can enable up to 30 events **per project** as conversions

So it looks like this limit applies per project.